# how to create Packed numeric style for current date in oracle

Tags: oracle, numeric, packed

Specify the day, month, and year as three INTEGER values with no separators between them, using these rules:

The day and month components must have two digits. When the day or month is less than 10, it must be preceded by a zero.

For any year, the year component can have four digits (for example, 1997). For years in the range 1950 to 2049, the year component can, alternatively, have two digits (50 represents 1950, and so on).

You cannot use any separators between the date components.

Examples: '240497' or '04241997'

Comment: Are you asking for the column type you need? Or the to_char formatting to achieve this against a DATE column? Little unclear what the question here is.

Comment: actually, i want to insert sysdate as a complete number e.g 240497 = 24-04-1997  that is equivalent to sysdate.

Comment: How is a date in 1997 equivalent to "sysdate"? Do you live 19 years in the past?

Comment: @mathguy sir. it was just an example ;

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's the question but you can format a date with `to_char`

```
select to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy')  as d
  from dual;
```

**OUPUT**

```
D       
--------
07092016
```

If you want to insert into a table

```
insert into t1 (field1)
values (to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy'));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer... its working within dual table. but its not working when is used it in an insert statement.

Comment: @NomiMehar what insert stament? You should post some more info on your question (destination table, is the data coming from another table...)

Comment: i have a table called 'EMP'. it has fields emp_id Numbers(7), first_name varchar2(20), last_name varchar2(20)..
now i want that when ever i insert a new record it automatically insert emp_id as current date in given format e.g 240497 that is equal to 24-04-19997

Comment: i have used this type of coding 
insert into t1 (field1)
values (to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy'));
 but it gives me error "literal does not match the format string"

Comment: thanks for the answers... its working now i have just change the datatype of emp_id to varchar2\

Comment: @NomiMehar Ok, good to know. I don't think is a good idea to store a date as emp_id since you probably can have 2 employees hired on the same date.